# Keeping focus in child component after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field in React, where I set the global name for my application.
I have the handlers set in the parent component called `App.js`

```
....
 state = {
    name: 'app_x',
    isProcessedData: false,
    isUploadedFiles: false, 
    isProcessedDBScan: false
}

setNameHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
}
  ...
```

in my child component, I refer to the state and the handler via `props`

```
export default function Home(props) {

    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Welcome to our application</p>   
            <TextField
                id="outlined-name"
                label="Name"
                className={"textfiled"}
                value={props.name}
                onChange={props.handleChange} //the textfield loses focus after each time the input is changed
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
           />
       </div>
    )
}
```

after each keystroke, the text field, is not focused anymore, because the entire UI is rendered.

I tried using `React.useState("app_x")`
for testing purposes, which worked fine, as long it's inside the component, but I need to pass down the state of the application to other components. 
Is there a way to solve this?

I thought about using refs, and then passing a `ref` down as a callback instead, but as far as the most use cases I have looked at it's mostly relevant inside the same component?

Comment: Try making a producible example, you shouldn't lose focus, for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-58027031-nolosefocus-lbjlt

Comment: What is the implementation of Textfield? This code looks good, your problem may be in the implementation of the Textfield component. Try swapping out Textfield with a input of type text and see if that changes things